# Issue with XPath not returning a value

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am fairly new to using XPath and XQuery and I can't seem to figure out why I am not able to return the OrderID from the following XML, using this XPath statement:

```
//OrderID[1]/text()
```

Why does it not find the `OrderID` or go any deeper than using this XPath?

```
//soap:Body
```

Here is the XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:rest="http://schemas.activebpel.org/REST/2007/12/01/aeREST.xsd"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <SubmitOnlineSearchResponse xmlns="http://eservices.diligenz.com/">
         <SubmitOnlineSearchResult>
            <return>
               <orderInfo>
                  <OrderID>75124507</OrderID>
               </orderInfo>
            </return>
         </SubmitOnlineSearchResult>
      </SubmitOnlineSearchResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why not using SOAP for SOAP?

Comment: I am using Informatica Real Time to get at the data. It is not a SOAP client.

Answer (score 2):

Because `OrderID` is in the `http://eservices.diligenz.com/` namespace.

If you can modify the message, add

```
xmlns:di="http://eservices.diligenz.com/"
```

to `soap:Envelope` along with the other namespace declarations and change your XPath to

```
//di:OrderID[1]/text()
```

If you cannot modify the message, use the hosting environment's facilities for binding namespace prefixes to namespaces, and bind `di` to `http://eservices.diligenz.com/` in order for the above XPath to work.

Comment: I am not able to modify the message, which is unfortunate. At least I was right on one of my hunches that it might be because of the namespace thing.

Comment: If you are using XQuery you can declare a namespace and prefix binding and then use that e.g. `declare namespace di="http://eservices.diligenz.com/"; //di:OrderID[1]/text()`. That does not require your to modify the source XML. If you can't declare namespaces you could use `//*:OrderID[1]/test()`, the `*` means any namespace.

Comment: @adamretter - The "any namespace" worked like a champ. That will come in very handy with this project.

Comment: @edgel1k Just be careful. As if you have more than one element of the same name in different namespaces then you may get more results than you expect; It is much better practice to declare the namespace!